# Прогрессбар для загрузки фото

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Добрый вечер пользователям портала. У меня есть форма для отправки фото на сервер.

```
<div class="progress-bar"><div class="progressing"></div></div>
<iframe id="support_upload_iframe" name="support_upload_iframe" width="200" height="300" style="border: none;"></iframe>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/system/modules/add_new_photo.php" target="support_upload_iframe">
<input id="support_add_img_file" type="file" name="file">
<input id="support_upload_iframe_submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Где `<div class="progress-bar">` - фон будущего прогрессбара, а `<div class="progressing">` - полоска загрузки.

И есть банальный файл-обработчик add_new_photo.php. Как можно сделать, чтобы в `<div class="progress-bar">` выводился прогрессбар загрузки изображения? "изображения будут HD качества"

Comment: Смотрите готовые решения: [Uploadify][1], [jQuery File Upload][2] (*демо, правда, сейчас не работает*)

   [1]:http://www.uploadify.com/demos/
   [2]:http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @Deonis, дело в том, что мне нужен собственный загрузчик, так как я потом даю пользователю возможность обрабатывать загруженное фото

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое и быстрое решение - использовать плагины для этого. Если будете писать свое решение, то столкнетесь с кучей проблем кроссбраузерности. Никто не мешает загрузить изображение через плагин и потом давать его обрабатывать.

***Но, если сильно хочется, то можно... :)***

Вот лучшее решение, которое я нашел: http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/. В конце весь код одним куском с очень хорошими комментариями. Это базовый код. Для его работы браузер должен поддерживать File API ([can i use?](http://caniuse.com/fileapi)). Если нужна кроссбраузерность, то нужно будет писать костыли (например, через iframe).

*Вот 2 функции из ссылки выше:*

Функция `uploadFile` получает файл для аплоада и вешает все обработчики. Конечно, в строке `xhr.open("POST", "UploadMinimal.aspx");` имя файла нужно заменить на свое, в котором идет сохранение иозображения. Если это будет php, то получить нужный файл вы сможете как `$_POST['fileToUpload']`.

```
function uploadFile() {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", "UploadMinimal.aspx");
        xhr.send(fd);
      }
```

Функция `uploadProgress` рассчитывает сколько процентов уже загружено и отображает эту информацию.

```
  function uploadProgress(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
      document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Vitalii-Maslianok Если честно: ничего не понял

Comment: тогда первый абзац моего ответа для вас